# Why does new Uri("/") in dotnet core 3.1behave differently in *nix and windows?

Tags: .net-core

The code below works in *nix but throws a `InvalidOperationException` in Windows

```
var res = new Uri("/");
```

I guess it has to do with the file:-delimiter (`\` for windows and `/` for *nix). But how/why?

Comment: And what exactly is the question? Uri constructor converts implicit file uris into explicit (file://...). ```/``` is an implicit file uri in unix. In windows it is not.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code IO path characters anyway. Use `Path.Combine` or `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Comment: @Morse Does dotnet fall back on an Uri being a part of a file system? MSDN says something about "implicit file path" but when it is considered such is not mentioned. Anything without scheme perhaps?